# Source code of the api

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Obviously the question was unclear.
I'm not in search of of the source code of the product. I'm looking for the sources of the api.
These sources are delivered within the MobileFirst Platform Studio for Eclipse.

So is there a publicly available jar file with the source, for example, of the interface:

```
com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticator
```

Developing for MFP one has to implement that interface and it would sure be helpful to read about the interfaces contract within the IDE instead of an browser.

Comment: Uhm, get hired at that company?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you be given the source code of the product?

The source code is not available.